# Restored iPhone 5s asks to set up as new iPhone or restore from backup

Tags: iphone, restore

I'm trying to restore my new iPhone 5s. I connected to iTunes and restored it. I enter the language, country and connected it to my Wi-Fi network. When I hit next it asks me if I want to Set up new iPhone or Restore from iTunes backup.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What suggestions are you looking? Are you asking us which option you should choose?

Answer (score 2):

It depends whether you have a backup you want to restore from. If you don't have a backup to restore from, or don't want to restore from a backup, set it up as a new phone. If you want to restore a backup, select the option for the backup that you want to restore from (iTunes or iCloud).